# User permissions

Tags: permissions

I am in need of some advice when it comes to user permission in Sharepoint online.

I want users to be able to add items on a subsite, but not be able to to view the site at all.

The idea is that they have their own page. Within this page they need to be able to submit infopath forms. I want these forms going to a subsite for the management to view, and only the management.

When I give users access to be able to submit(add items) it automatically give access to view the site. I do not want this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that info path form instead of giving permissions on that sub site list.
Configure submit button option, where users can submit data,redirect to your desired sites list there and it is done.

Comment: Thank you JP Nayak for your response. Could you please elaborate on how to configure infopath todo such, From what I have seen I cannot seem to add a seperate set of permissions for the submission. Or are you refering to having a workflow setup to move the file once it has been submittted?? thank you again

Comment: I am not saying anything about permission on submission. You have a subsite which you want to be hidden from users ,So do not give any access to them there, 
Now you can configure new item  in users' individual page  by infopath as you have mentioned above , configure submit button there to your desired central location (subsite/library) .

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I have tried as you say. but when I login as my test user. It says that I do not have permission to submit data. Even if i give them full rights to their site. It seems that when the form is submitted to my subsite they need access to add documents?? Or am i missing something? (I am new to all of this)

Comment: Well, in that case you can give only "add items"  in list permission  by changing edit or contribute permission levels.

Comment: but there in there lies my problem. In order to give them add access they also automatically get view access. which we do not want

Comment: NO you can give only "add items" permission without giving any other access,it is possible. You just play around with permissions.